# Read local json into array of type interface

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I want to read a local JSON file and put the content to an array of type InputData. The JSON consists of many entries, which also have the format of InputData. I tried to realize my requirements with the following code.

The problem appears at the subscription "TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type '{}'."

If I can't subscribe the JSON, how can I read the entries and push them to my array?

```
    import dataset from "dataset.json";
    
    export interface InputData {
      _id: {
        $oid: String;
      };
      id: String;
      expNumber: Number;
      passed: Boolean;
    }
    
    @Component({
      selector: "app-read-data",
      templateUrl: "./read-data.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./read-data.component.scss"],
    })
    export class ReadDataComponent implements OnInit {
      
      public data:InputData[];
    
      constructor() {}
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dataset.subscribe(readData => {
        readData.reduce(t => this.data.push(t));
      });
      console.log("DATA", this.data);
    }
```

Here is an example for the JSON File:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "51275"
  },
  "id": "T22F2r",
  "expNumber": 2,
  "passed": false
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "23451"
  },
  "id": "r3322F",
  "expNumber": 2,
  "passed": true
}]
```

Comment: Who downgraded this question???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The imported json is treated like a constant object, it is not an observable.
It should be enough to assign it.

```
public data: InputData[] = dataset;
```

Note: It would be an observable, if you call dataset.json with http from assets.

Comment: I tried this before but I got the error : "TS2740: Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'InputData[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more." so I though I need to iterate over the dataset to put it into "data".

Comment: I did a small change at your code and now it works. Thank you!

public data: InputData[] = dataset as InputData[];

Comment: @JukeboxHero what was that small change? I get EXACTLY that error with '26 more' and have been struggling all afternoon to resolve it.

Comment: I found the problem. I had to change my import statements from ```import * as configData from '../../config.json';``` to ```import configData from '../../config.json';``` I got the former from some tutorial. Maybe old verion of Angular